# can i pass interface to a service in android?

Tags: android

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void aMethod();
}
```

My custom activity:

```
public class MyObject extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          start(5,MyInterface handle);
    }
     public void start(final int duration,  MyInterface handle){ 
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),myService.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            //Eroor !*** i can't pass handle.aMethod() to my service ***
            bundle.putSerializable("handle",bundle.getSerializable(handle.aMethod()));
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startService(intent);
    }
}
```

I have a service:

```
public class myService extends Service {
}
```

I want implement my interface method in my service. my activity pass interface method to service and start it.

I can't pass handle.aMethod() to my service.

How can i pass an interface to a service in an activity method?

Comment: Why you want to pass ` interface to a service` ?

Comment: You should into this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611527/passing-data-from-activity-to-service-through-interface

Comment: Seems like you want to call interface method from service ??

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K , i need it!!

Comment: @ Piyush Kukadiya Yes! i want implement interface method in my service

Comment: sure you can if the service is a local one (hosted by the same process): use "local bound service" pattern

Comment: @ pskink can you guide me to  "local bound service" ?!

Comment: just ask mr google for `local bound service`

Comment: You can use https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html to make direct call from activity to service

Answer (score 1):

That cannot work.Because getSerializable() save the object's fields exclude the object's "ID".So while your service receive the object, this two objects are not equal.They are not the same object in JVM ,though they have the same fields.

You can use AIDL to solve this problem.
Use bindService() to get service binder, and pass AIDL interface to service.

https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/os/Binder.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with some library ? It will help you to pass data from anywhere to anywhere.

like `EventBus` https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

and `OTTO` http://square.github.io/otto/

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

hey you want to implement your defined interface method in your service, so you can use **`implements`** key  word. like this

```
 public class myService extends Service implements  MyInterface {
}
```

it will ask for override your interface method, in your service  and you can use it in your service 
Let me know if have any confusion.